# Put a string into dictionary Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split

Basically, I have the following file:

```
Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain
Paris, 343 boulevard Saint-Germain
Marseille, 343 boulevard Camille Flammarion
Marseille, 29 rue Camille Desmoulins
Marseille, 1 chemin des Aubagnens
Paris, 12 rue des singes
Paris, 34 quai VoLtAiRe
Paris, 34 rue Voltaire
Lille, 120 boulevard Victor Hugo
Marseille, 50 rue Voltaire
Toulouse, 90 rue Voltaire
Marseille, 78 boulevard de la libération
Lille, 30 rue Victor Danel
Mont Saint Martin, 42 rue de Lyon
Mont de Marsan, 100 avenue Pierre de Coubertin
Strasbourg, 391 boulevard de Nancy
Lyon, 56 rue du Docteur Albéric Pont
Lille, 90 rue d'Arras
Lille, 76 impasse Georges Pompidou
Lyon, 2 allée des fleurs
```

Let's consider the first line

```
Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain
```

I'd like to split that string and then add 'Paris' as a key in a dictionary, and add "468 boulevard Saint-Germain" as a value.

Then, the following line is

```
Paris, 343 boulevard Saint-Germain
```

As I already have Paris in my dictionary, I'd like to add "343 boulevard Saint-Germain" as a second value for Paris.

So far I have the following code:

```
import os, sys
import functions

class Addresses:

    def __init__(self):

        self.city = ""
        self.address = ""

addresses = {}

print("Hello")
userInput = input("Type a key : ")
if userInput == 'q':
    line = functions.myReadline(sys.argv[1])
    for line in line:
        addresses[line] = Addresses()
        addresses[line].city = line.split(',')
        addresses[line].address = line.split(',')
    for address in addresses.values():
        print("{0} : adresse correspondante {1}".format(address.city, address.address))
else:
    print("non")
```

Basically I want {0} to be the city and {1} to be the address. But when I execute it, here is what it gives to me:

```
Hello
Type a key : q
['Paris', ' 458 boulevard Saint-Germain'] : adresse correspondante ['Paris', ' 458 boulevard Saint-Germain']
['Paris', ' 343 boulevard Saint-Germain'] : adresse correspondante ['Paris', ' 343 boulevard Saint-Germain']
['Marseille', ' 343 boulevard Camille Flammarion'] : adresse correspondante ['Marseille', ' 343 boulevard Camille Flammarion']
['Marseille', ' 29 rue Camille Desmoulins'] : adresse correspondante ['Marseille', ' 29 rue Camille Desmoulins']
['Marseille', ' 1 chemin des Aubagnens'] : adresse correspondante ['Marseille', ' 1 chemin des Aubagnens']
['Paris', ' 12 rue des singes'] : adresse correspondante ['Paris', ' 12 rue des singes']
['Paris', ' 34 quai VoLtAiRe'] : adresse correspondante ['Paris', ' 34 quai VoLtAiRe']
['Paris', ' 34 rue Voltaire'] : adresse correspondante ['Paris', ' 34 rue Voltaire']
['Lille', ' 120 boulevard Victor Hugo'] : adresse correspondante ['Lille', ' 120 boulevard Victor Hugo']
['Marseille', ' 50 rue Voltaire'] : adresse correspondante ['Marseille', ' 50 rue Voltaire']
['Toulouse', ' 90 rue Voltaire'] : adresse correspondante ['Toulouse', ' 90 rue Voltaire']
['Marseille', ' 78 boulevard de la libération'] : adresse correspondante ['Marseille', ' 78 boulevard de la libération']
['Lille', ' 30 rue Victor Danel'] : adresse correspondante ['Lille', ' 30 rue Victor Danel']
['Mont Saint Martin', ' 42 rue de Lyon'] : adresse correspondante ['Mont Saint Martin', ' 42 rue de Lyon']
['Mont de Marsan', ' 100 avenue Pierre de Coubertin'] : adresse correspondante ['Mont de Marsan', ' 100 avenue Pierre de Coubertin']
['Strasbourg', ' 391 boulevard de Nancy'] : adresse correspondante ['Strasbourg', ' 391 boulevard de Nancy']
['Lyon', ' 56 rue du Docteur Albéric Pont'] : adresse correspondante ['Lyon', ' 56 rue du Docteur Albéric Pont']
['Lille', " 90 rue d'Arras"] : adresse correspondante ['Lille', " 90 rue d'Arras"]
['Lille', ' 76 impasse Georges Pompidou'] : adresse correspondante ['Lille', ' 76 impasse Georges Pompidou']
['Lyon', ' 2 allée des fleurs'] : adresse correspondante ['Lyon', ' 2 allée des fleurs']
```

Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: You cannot use lists as keys, since keys should be immutable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you mean? I'd basically like to sort my file in order to get each address for Paris, each address for Marseille, and each address for every possibly cities I could have. What would be the best way then?

Comment: The key of your addresses dict is the whole line from the file and every value is a list of two values! You have to do a split first and assign each value of the split list accordingly

Comment: would you like to have a dict with multiple addresses per city? e.g. `{"Paris": ['458...', '453 ...',], ...}`

Comment: @LaurIvan yes, EXACTLY!!!

Comment: But you already have such a list, if all you want is to print it back you don't need to parse it at all.

Comment: @zwer It is for an auto-completion project. User will be typing "Pa", I need to show him Paris, and then he'll start typing a number, I need to show him the possible addresses in Paris with that number. So I was thinking of using a dictionary to do that... Maybe I'm wrong tho.

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste - dictionaries are good for fast lookup of hashed values, they (alone) won't help you much if you want to do character by character lookup - create a [`Trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of your data if you want to do fast character-by-character lookups.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't know if for line in line gives you any naming convention conflicts but it probably does
2. I reworked the structure because yours might already be flawed in terms of logic, and since it is a pretty short piece of code, so this should probably solve your problem:

   ```
   dictionary = {}

   for line in lines:
       city_and_address = line.split(",")
       if city_and_address[0] in dictionary:
           dictionary[city_and_address[0]].append(city_and_address[1])
       else:
           dictionary[city_and_address[0]] = [city_and_address[1]]
   ```

Comment: Or shorter, no if else needed: `addresses.setdefault(city, []).append(address)`

Answer (score 0):

Should you not do:

```
addresses[line] = Addresses()
parts = line.split(',')
addresses[line].city = parts[0]
addresses[line].address = part[1]
```

?

Comment: I did try to do that, but Parts[0] gave me the first character (so "P" for example) and parts[1] the second one ('a' for Paris)... :(

Comment: Then make sure that the 'line' variable contains the "Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain" strings.

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste Then please add that code as an alternative code to your question

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
"Paris": "458 boulevard Saint-Germain",
```

instead of:

```
Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain
```